# Get window xid via process name in XFCE4

Tags: linux, bash

I'm working with customization of polybar and desided to make a button for cmus, which hide/bring (to hidden workspase) the player. As cmus client works in terminal I need to get terminal xid first, then send it to workspase (or bring back). So I need to do something like this:

```
wmctrl -ir 0x028001a7 -t 1
```

But the problem is that i can get title, pid, or xid, using:

```
wmctrl -lp
```

But player have a song's name as a tittle. Also I can try:

```
pidof cmus
```

It gives me pid, but there are several xid's for one pid (terminal pid). So I can't grep it by pid. How can I get xid of process? List of processes is also great. Just for fun I can get a songname from cmus-server, then find the xid by that songname in title. Hope you smile and like this method, but I don't.Thanks.